# Antlr: failing predicate results in not further alternatives exploration

Tags: c#, antlr4

After the upgrade from Antlr 4.6.6 to 4.13.1, a specific unit test for a large grammar stopped being recognized. The grammar has a similar structure as:

```
Rule0 -> Rule1 | Rule2 | Rule3
Rule1 -> Rule4 | Rule5 
Rule4 -> Rule9 | {predicate()}? expression1
Rule2 -> Rule6 | Rule7
Rule7 -> Rule8 | expression2
```

The grammar is too hairy and complex to share completely, so sorry for this.

The idea is that both `expression1` and `expression2` recognize my UT.
I can't change the order of the rules in Rule0, because of other priority issues.
I debugged, and I know the predicate is returning a false value.
Nevertheless, the recognition process fails.

If I get into `Rule4` and remove the `expression1` alternative, the parser recognizes my test.

I suppose this happens because the whole expression was recognized, and then the predicate was false (as Antlr does not do any backtracking).

Is there any simple solution for this kind of situation? Other than rewriting the grammar completely?

Comment: Can you include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Print out the parse tree after the failed parse and see what it is thinking that it's trying to recognize. Run with a DiagnosticErrorListener and see what it is doing. It sounds like you have an ambiguous grammar. You may well need to  either insert more predicates or rewrite to straighten this out.

Comment: Accepted the parsing and handled in the semantic action. Not perfect, but will work.